# Алгоритм построения расписания. Период дат

Tags: алгоритм, ruby

Добрый день.
Помогите пожалуйста построить алгоритм.
Есть массив рейсов, ниже один из рейсов.

```
2017/2018 = год
1..52 = номера недель
1..7 номера дней
```

то есть запись `2017=> { 8=>[2, 5, 7] }` означает что рейс совершает перелет в 2017 году на 8-ой неделе, во вторник, пятницу и воскресенье

```
hash = {
  :airline=>'U6',
  :flight_number=>'873',
  :origin=>'PEK',
  :destination=>'BKK',
  :dates=>[
    {
      2017=>
        {
          8=>[2, 5, 7],
          9=>[2, 5, 7],
          10=>[2, 5, 7],
          11=>[2, 5, 7],
          12=>[1, 2, 5, 7],
          13=>[2, 5, 7],
          14=>[2, 5, 7],
          15=>[2, 5],
          27=>[2, 5, 7],
          28=>[2, 5, 7],
          29=>[2, 5, 7],
          30=>[2, 5, 7],
          31=>[2, 5, 7],
          32=>[2, 5, 7],
          33=>[2, 5, 7],
          34=>[2, 5, 7],
          35=>[2],
          49=>[5, 7],
          50=>[2, 5, 7],
          51=>[2, 5, 7],
          52=>[2, 5, 7]
        }
    },
    {
      2018=>{
        1=>[2, 5, 7],
        2=>[2, 5, 7],
        3=>[2, 5, 7],
        4=>[2, 5, 7],
        5=>[2, 5, 7],
        6=>[2, 5, 7],
        7=>[2, 5, 7],
        8=>[2, 5, 7],
        9=>[2, 5, 7],
        10=>[2, 5, 7],
        11=>[2, 5, 7],
        12=>[2, 5]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

не могу придумать алгоритм, как разложить хеш на четыре периода

```
U6 873 PEK BKK -2--5-7 2017/02/21 - 2017/04/14 (- 8..15 недели)
U6 873 PEK BKK 1------ 2017/03/20 - 2017/03/20 (- 12 неделя)
U6 873 PEK BKK -2--5-7 2017/07/04 - 2017/08/29 (- 27..35 недели)
U6 873 PEK BKK -2--5-7 2017/12/08 - 2018/03/23 (- 49..52..1..12 недели)
```

Comment: Не знаю как на руби, но я видимо шел бы по хешу недель в порядке возрастания ключа запоминал бы текущее значение элемента массива на будущее и основным действием сверял текущее значение с запомненным и если совпадает наращивал бы дату окончания. если же значения различны - то пишем накопленный период на выход и начинаем запоминать новый, т.е. сохраняем дату начала и дату окончания в одну неделю

Comment: Потому что, вероятно, вы ещё сами не решили, что хотите :) Если вы хотите вычислить периоды с постоянным недельным расписанием, то у вас их будет не 4, а 9 (!).

Comment: Хм, хотя я, кажется, сейчас разобрался, о чём вы, вы хотите, чтобы периоды могли начинаться и кончаться посреди недели, а также допускать пересечения. Но в таком случае речь у вас уже не прямо о неделях, а о **диапазонах дат с днями недели**. Но алгоритма, дающего однозначный результат, я сейчас тоже сходу не вижу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Объединить недели в общий массив. Желаемый результат:

```
:dates_2017_2018 = [
    8=>[2, 5, 7],
...
    52=>[2, 5, 7],
    53=>[2, 5, 7],
... 
    63=>[2, 5, 7],
    64=>[2, 5]
]
```

Учесть, что в будущем год не всегда заканчивается в воскресенье.

2. Построить периоды для каждого дня недели, считая понедельник нулевым днём недели. Желаемый результат:

```
:periods_2017_2018 = [
  {
     1=>
        {
          [12*7,12*7]
        },
     2=>
        {
          [8*7+1, 15*7+1],
          [27*7+1, 35*7+1],
          [50*7+1, 64*7+1]
        },
     5=>
        {
          [8*7+4, 15*7+4],
          [27*7+4, 34*7+4],
          [49*7+4, 64*7+4]
        },
     7=>
        {
          [8*7+6, 14*7+6],
          [27*7+6, 34*7+6],
          [49*7+6, 63*7+6]
        }
  }
]
```

Всего 10 периодов.

3. Склеить полученные подмассивы по алгоритму:

A. Инициализация: `id1=1`.

B. Для каждого периода из подмассива с `id1` провести склеивание с периодами следующих за ним подмассивов.

B1. Для каждого `id2>id1`:

B1.1. Создать подмассив с `id3 = 10*id1+id2`.

B1.2. Проверить условия склеивания с каждым периодом подмассива.

Условие склеивания: различие между началами периодов не более 6 дней и между концами тоже.

Если условие склеивания выполнено, то:

в подмассив `id3"` записать более раннее начало и более поздний конец по склеенным периодам;
склеенные периоды удалить из обоих подмассивов.

B1.3. Если по окончании п.B1.2 подмассив с `id3"` пуст, его следует удалить. Если непуст, то установить флаг `change`.

B2. Если флаг `change` установлен, то удалить все пустые подмассивы и записать `ready="id1"`.

B3. Упорядочить индексы подмассивов в алфавитном порядке (1, 12, 2,..) и искать индекс `id1`, следующий после `ready`.
Если такой индекс найден, то перейти к п.3.

Желаемый результат:

```
:periods_2017_2018 = [
  {
     1=>
        {
          [12*7,12*7]
        },
     257=>
        {
          [8*7+1, 15*7+4],
          [27*7+1, 35*7+1],
          [49*7+4, 64*7+4]
        }
  }
]
```

И остаётся только сформировать отчёт.